# how to fix errors , after add screen using get_cli in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, get-cli

[image: 1]

how  i fix this eroors
Undefined name 'ConfigEnvironments'.

Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
Undefined name 'Environments'.

Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
Undefined name 'Environments'.

Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
Target of URI doesn't exist: '../../config.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist.

I actually  want to fix these , errors i dont understand what actually this errors are

Answer (score 0):

It goes wrong on the line

```
import '../../config.dart';
```

It means it can't find the file. Two dots means go up a folder. And it does this twice. One up is to the folder `infrastructure` and the second to `lib`. And there is no file called `config.dart` in the folder `lib`.